# How do I create a WPF C# Application that pops up at a certain date and time set by the user?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, timer

I need it to be sort of like this application here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cw6Ml6gZqU8

It is a reminder.  The user types in notes and then sets a date and time the form will pop back up.  It is a Windows form App.  However I need help with an WPF application that the user sets a certain date and time (say 3/15/2013 at 10:00p.m.) to run an event.  Once the user sets the date and time, then they name the timer and save it.  So far I have already added the .dll etc needed for a TimePicker (not available in WPF, but in an extended class from Windows forms).

I really need a start and so far all I have found is utilizing the Dispatch Timer class, but it only sets the time.  Not finding any good resources.  I will take article suggestions too!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Quartz](http://nuget.org/packages/Quartz/) library. It provides functionality to schedule tasks in a way you describe.

Task scheduling [might not be that simple](http://ayende.com/blog/155489/rotten-scheduling-dont-roll-your-own) as you think.

Comment: I have used Quartz or at least a portion of the Quartz library, but with Java.  Nevertheless it was only a very small piece of a major project.  So I have an idea of what it should look like and I know it is not simple!  Which is why I am asking for more info, but I need the user to be able to schedule it.  Thanks for the reply!!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a thread or backgroundworker that check every minute the datetime using "DateTime.now()" then display a poupup dialog.

You'll need a process running anyways, but you can set it as a background process until the reminder apears...